# Have fullscreen cover 2 displays

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, fullscreen

I would like to have a fullscreen display covering two side by side monitors (i.e half of the view on one screen and half of the image on the other side). This means a mode in which "fullscreen" is limited to one monitor, having it cover the space taken by both monitors.

Anyone have an idea on how this could be achieved ?